# Highchart Click - Extrafield

Tags: jquery, events, click, highcharts

We are using Highcharts api in our application. http://jsfiddle.net/hitser/k7eDR/2/

I have this series array:

```
[{"showInLegend":false,"name":"J_02","data":[20,17,26,25],"extrafield":["<b>Time:
</b>05:44:45S<b>Speed:</b>20Km\h<b>Lat:</b>4.666810 <b>Long:</b>-74.111214","<b>Time:
</b>05:46:47<b>Speed:</b>17Km\h<b>Lat:</b>4.672675<b>Long:</b>-74.105377"," <b>Time:
</b>05:50:54<b>Speed:</b>26Km\h<b>Lat:</b>4.689762<b>Long:</b>-74.093102","<b>Time:
</b>05:57:02<b>Speed:</b>25Km\h<b>Lat:</b>7.390400<b>Long:</b>-74.073021"]}]
```

As I can do an alert event for each point to show me:

```
Name :J_02
Time : 05:44:45
Speed :20Km/h
Lat:4.666810
Long:74.111214
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried ? How about search for extra data and click event on Highcharts ?

Comment: Why `extrafield` is an array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it on click event by the following.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    alert(this.series.options.extrafield[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you want to get it according to the clicked point position you can use `x` as index.

```
alert(this.series.options.extrafield[ this.x ]);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/fhQGA/)